# Which data structure should be used while storing large number of data, but not any RDBMS?

Tags: algorithm, database

This question was asked in an interview. First, I came up with B-tree. He asked me to be more specific and asked me to describe how I would store the data so that it would be easier to retrieve.
Can you please throw some light on this. Thanks in advance

Comment: The question is not clear: "storing large number of data, but not any RDBMS" - I don't know how to parse that.

Comment: I was asked the same question. You should not use any RDBMS, but ay primitive data structure would do.

Comment: I would speak in terms of entities.  Then, with respect to Normalization rules I'd review the entities for better structure with respect to business rules & relationships between entities.  It was a difficult question, made to see how you respond rather than your answer.

Comment: Then the question is completely under-specified.  What are we trying to optimize here?  Insertion speed?  Query speed?  Cache behaviour?  Storage overhead?  Something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You question isn't really clear. 
"Good" ways to store the data depend on what you want to do with it.

If you want access parts of your data, a list of offsets suffices. If you want to search in text, using an additional inverted index in combonation with docIds->offsets is great. If you have frequent updates to your data and reading is rare, none of those make sense. So it really depends

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like an open question, so you can demonstrate your vast experience of ... well, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL would be my guess, but you could argue that http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dbm answers the question.